# How to connect to Ethereum URLs created using AWS blockchain template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, blockchain, ethereum

I've just finished setting up a Ethereum Stack using the AWS Blockchain Template according to the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/blockchain-templates/latest/developerguide/blockchain-templates-getting-started.html) 
I've sshed to the EC2 instance (bastion host) from my local machine and I can hit the EthStats URL via curl from the bastion host but when I try to go tot he url from chrome, it gives 'This site can’t be reached' error, even though I've setup a FireProxy as per the instructions in the docs. 
How do I connect to the Ethereum URLs given in outputs of my Ethereum stack in the AWS CloudFormation console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup the SOCKS proxy also only setting fire proxy wont work.
check the link below ,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/blockchain-templates/latest/developerguide/blockchain-templates-ethereum.html

At the end of documentation there are instruction to set up Socks proxy.